# Check if coordinate belongs to square, given NE and SW corrds of region

Tags: javascript, coordinates

### Background

I a coordinate and I need to know if it is inside a square. To achieve this I am given the NorthEast and SouthWest coordinates of this square.

### Code

So far I came up with the following code:

```
const isInsideSquare = (center, northEast, southWest) =>
    southWest.lat < center.lat  &&
    northEast.lat  > center.lat &&
    northEast.lng  < center.lng &&
    southWest.lng > center.lng;
```

However, this code fails with the following example:

```
const northEast = {lat: 42.1539732831, lng: -4.7027107182};
const southWest = {lat: 36.8340642391, lng: -11.5965440996};
const coord = {lat: 38.7223, lng: -9.1393};

console.log(isInsideSquare(coord, northEat, southWest));   //false
```

### Problem

The problem is that my function returns false, instead of true. As you can see, the `coord`is inside the square:

https://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/?id=59e70fdf5c8578.99150744

But somehow I am missing it.

### Question

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: If you look at your coords, you'll notice that the `northEast.lng  < center.lng` and `southWest.lng > center.lng` conditions are wrong.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, your accepted answer is plain wrong. If you check some coordinates with positive lng you'll see that it fails again. you have to deal with the fact, that the values on the longitude are on a circle, and you get values from -180 to +180, and -175° and +175° can be both 10° apart and 350° apart. Depending on wich segment you mean.

Comment: @Thomas

**Negative lng**:

`let northEast = {lat: 42.1539732831, lng: -4.7027107182};`

`let southWest = {lat: 36.8340642391, lng: -11.5965440996};`

`let coord = {lat: 38.7223, lng: -9.1393};`

`console.log(isInsideSquare(coord, northEast, southWest));   // true`


**Positive lng**


`southWest = {lat: 36.8340642391, lng: 4.7027107182};`

`northEast = {lat: 42.1539732831, lng: 11.5965440996};`

`coord = {lat: 38.7223, lng: 9.1393};`

`console.log(isInsideSquare(coord, northEast, southWest)); //true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
const isInsideSquare = (center, northEast, southWest) =>
  southWest.lat < center.lat  &&
  northEast.lat  > center.lat &&
  northEast.lng  > center.lng && // <-- this condition reversed
  southWest.lng < center.lng;    // <-- this condition reversed
```

Cause both latitude and longtitude in the southWest edge are greater than coordinates in the center. And both coordinates in northEast should be lower.

Comment: The greater thans and less thans are different.

Comment: So the top **right** corner of a rectangle should be to the **left** of the coordinate? and the bottom **left** to the **right** of that coordinate? Your answer makes no sense in the given context.

Comment: southWest is a right top corner and northEast is a bottom left corner. And the center coordinate should be between those two values. Why doesn't it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

on the longitude you deal with a circle, and your angles wrap around, you have to deal with that, or normalizing it somehow

```js
const normalizeDegrees = v => v < 0 ? 360 + v % 360 : v % 360;

const isInsideSquare = (center, northEast, southWest) => (
  southWest.lat < center.lat &&
  northEast.lat > center.lat &&
  normalizeDegrees(center.lng - southWest.lng) < normalizeDegrees(northEast.lng - southWest.lng));

const northEast = {
  lat: 42.1539732831,
  lng: -4.7027107182
};
const southWest = {
  lat: 36.8340642391,
  lng: -11.5965440996
};
const coord = {
  lat: 38.7223,
  lng: -9.1393
};

console.log(isInsideSquare(coord, northEast, southWest));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

center is less **degrees to the east** of southwest than northEast is.

Comment: Very insteresting! Could you provide an example where my function fails and yours does not?